# PHP - Fatal Error: Call to undefined method - but method exist

Tags: php, methods

I'm currently creating a ticket handler system, however, I keep getting a very surprising error when I try to call one of my classes.
The error is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method makeTickets::submitNewTicket() in /home/shortcut/public_html/MYDOMAIN/explore/account/tickets.php on line 68
```

However, the method I'm trying to use is definitely defined in my class, and it is being printed out in get_class_methods... I'm at a loss at what to do. 
Here's the main code that's calling the method.

```
            require_once('app/makeTickets.php');
            $etickets = new makeTickets($loggedInUser);
            print_r(get_class_methods($etickets));
            $etickets->submitNewTicket();
```

Here is the actual class itself.

```
<?php
class makeTickets {
    public $id;
    public $user;
    public function __construct($user){
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->id = $user->user_id;
    }
    public function viewNewTicket(){
        ?>
            <div class="cards">
                <div class="default full-width alert">
                    <h3 class="default alert"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Create New Ticket</h3>
                    <form class="field" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="title-editor" placeholder="Ticket Title" name="title"/>
                    <textarea id="content" name="content"></textarea>
                    </form>
                    <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace('content')
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        return;
    }
    public function sumbitNewTicket(){
        // @todo constructor
        foreach (glob('*.json') as $item){
            echo 'Detected '.$item.'<br>';
        }
        return;
    }
}
?>
```

As for the output, here is the result of my code:
[image]
As you can see, the class method which I'm trying to call is being printed out, so I'm not too sure what's wrong.
Thanks for any/all help!

Comment: You have a typo. Sumbit and Submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Change sumbitNewTicket to submitNewTicket.

Comment: Awk. I looked at the spelling and thought they were the same. Oh my. Accepting this answer in 7 min.